# Set dimensions of a mesh in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a `GameObject` with a Quad `MeshFilter`. It is dimensionally 1x1 by default, and I can change its size by setting its scale, but that also resizes all of its child elements relative to the change in scale. I have tried giving it a `RectTransform` but changing the width and height does not appear to change its size. The regular Transform component does not have width or height controls.

How can I set the size of a mesh in Unity without scaling all child elements?

Comment: You want to upload image of the child GameObjects you don't want to resize? This is will be helpful in order to come up with a solution...

Comment: What are your child objects (that don't need transform from parent)? Do you need some scaled and some not?

Answer (score 1):

Unity treats meshes, as well as images and sounds, as assets that are created outside of the application. Of course, in Unity you can move 3d models around, scale and rotate them, but these are very basic 3d modelling capabilities, and you won't be able to properly edit 3d models in it. Personally, I think that this is enough only for rough prototypes made out of scaled cubes.

So, if you want to modify these assets, you can:

1. Open up a separate application (Blender, 3ds Max, Maya for 3d models) and create a mesh you want. This is probably the solution that you want.
2. Create a script that will change [Mesh object](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh.html) in runtime. While it's a good solution for some problems, it's probably not what you're looking for.
3. Use one of third-party packages that bring 3d modelling capabilities to Unity, such as [ProBuilder](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/11919). Please be aware that I haven't used it and it's not a recommendation — I'm just showing that this alternative exists.

Answer (score 0):

You need to calculate it :)

1. Take current bounds from renderer component. This is your real object size on the scene.
2. Calc your new scale for expected bounds.

As example you have:

`actualBounds.x` is `100`

Scale in all dimensions is `1`.

```
var expectedBoundX = 150   
var newScaleX = expectedBoundX / (actualBounds.x/scaleX);
```

And afterwards just set this `newScaleX` to `X` scale :)